# Correct measures to place the page number in an absolute position on diferent pages (titleps)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, titleps

I'm trying to find the correct measurements to be able to place the page number at the bottom right of a document using `titleps` and the `l3doc` class. The problem is that I use different measurements for the margins somewhere in the document and the position of the page numbers doesn't look good. I don't want to use a second style, the place where I change the page dimensions is an 'index' and it would be more problematic to change at this point.

On the first pages it looks like this:
[image: output]

and in the others it looks like this:
[image: good]

And I want them to look like the numbers on all the pages as in the second picture, but I can't find the correct measures to align the numbers. The MWE:

```
\documentclass{l3doc}
\usepackage[top=0.5in,bottom=0.3in,left=2in,right=0.7in,footskip=0.2in,headheight=1cm,headsep=0.27cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[osf,mono=false,scale=0.95,llscaled=0.95]{libertine}
\usepackage[sf,bf,compact,medium,pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\newpagestyle{myheader}[\color{MediumBlue}\small\sffamily]{%
\setfoot{}%
        {}%
        {\rlap{\parbox{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax}{\hspace{5pt}\thepage\,/\,\pageref{LastPage}}}}%
}
\pagestyle{myheader}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
% other margins for index
\newgeometry{top=0.5in,bottom=0.3in,left=1.0in,right=0.5in,footskip=0.2in,headheight=1cm,headsep=0.27cm}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, are not the "exact measurements" but solve the problem of the position of page numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=0.5in,bottom=0.3in,left=2in,right=0.7in,footskip=0.2in,headheight=1cm,headsep=0.27cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[osf,mono=false,scale=0.95,llscaled=0.95]{libertine}
\usepackage[sf,bf,compact,medium,pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\newpagestyle{myheader}[\color{MediumBlue}\small\sffamily]{%
\setfoot{\rlap{\hskip\dimexpr-\oddsidemargin-1in\relax%
         \parbox{1.93\paperwidth\relax}{\hfil\thepage\,/\,\pageref{LastPage}}}}%
        {}%
        {}%
}
\pagestyle{myheader}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
% other margins
\newgeometry{top=0.5in,bottom=0.3in,left=1.0in,right=0.5in,footskip=0.2in,headheight=1cm,headsep=0.27cm}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```